# Updating an Eloquent model with custom attributes

Tags: php, laravel, model, attributes, eloquent

I have a model that has two extra attributes which are not stored in the database, but contain request-specific information that I need. The values of these properties can be derived from the saved data inside the database, that's why they don't have their own columns in the table.

When updating this model I see it tries to pass in the declared properties in `protected $attributes [...]` into the update query. Can this be disabled because obviously there are no columns for my properties in `$attributes` array.

This is a part of my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/**
 * Class SurveyQuestionAnswer
 * @package App
 */
class SurveyQuestionAnswer extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['label', 'value', 'index'];

    protected $attributes = ['labelParsed', 'hasOneOrMoreParameters'];

    // more model code ...
}
```

And when the update-method on the model is called I get this error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into`survey_question_answers`(`0`,`1`,`label`,`value`,`index`,`survey_question_id`,`updated_at`,`created_at`) values (labelParsed, hasOneOrMoreParameters, My custom answer label, 1, 1, 23, 2016-01-14 08:01:32, 2016-01-14 08:01:32))`

As you can see it tries to put `labelParsed` and `hasOneOrMoreParameters` into the query. But I want to disable that behavior. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) can be used to add extra attributes to the eloquent result object.

## Model

```
public function getlabelParsedAttribute()
{
    return 'some value';
}
```

This will then be accessible like so:

```
$surveyQuestionAnswer = SurveyQuestionAnswer::find(1);

$labelParsed = $surveyQuestionAnswer->label_parsed;
```

Comment: So there's no need to add them (also) in the attributes property? Because I have those `get***Attribute` methods declared.

Comment: I see this works like a charm. I may have misunderstood somewhere that I had to also add those accessors to the attributes property. Thanks, +1 and accepted.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the $attributes property, but I get the impression that it creates both an accessor and mutator with a default value for a given attribute . Also worth bearing in mind that accessors/mutators are not included if you use the toArray() method on your eloquent results, or at least they didn't used to be.

Comment: if you want those custom accessor added to the output of `toArray` you can use the `$appends` var on the model. [Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Serialization - Appending](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)